# Silverlight: How to deploy a Silverlight app?

Tags: silverlight, deployment, out-of-browser, xap

I've just written a Silverlight app and want to deploy it. This app is NOT to be hosted at a website. It is supposed to be a standalone app, just like a standalone WPF app for Windows, but (if I understand Silverlight correctly) it can run on both Windows and Mac.

I've created a .xap file. What do I do with this file to get the app installed? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *do* need to install it *from a website* as it still requires the Silverlight environment provided by the browser plugin.

It is the browser plugin that provides the OOB (Out Of Browser) mode.

I gather Adobe Air has the same requirements for apps.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what @HiTech Magic stated, you can also create a [standalone installer](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/install/slsetup.aspx) for silverlight OOB apps using `SLLauncher.exe`.